# AlignTransition doest work on column in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have observed that AlignTransition does not work on column and it works if we have stack. I am unable to figure out the exact issue with the column.

```
Column(
    children: [
      Visibility(
          visible: controller.isWelcomeHeader ? false : true,
          child: const QuestionHeader()),
      AlignTransition(
        alignment: controller.animation,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: ScreenUtil.screenHeight - marginQuestion,
          width: ScreenUtil.screenWidth,
          child: const Question(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

and it Align Transition will ] work with the stack

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Visibility(
          visible: controller.isWelcomeHeader ? false : true,
          child: const QuestionHeader()),
      AlignTransition(
        alignment: controller.animation,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: ScreenUtil.screenHeight - marginQuestion,
          width: ScreenUtil.screenWidth,
          child: const Question(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

After wrapping the AlignTransition widget in colum with sizebox or container, giving it height and width, it should work.

```
Column(
  children: [
   Visibility(
      visible: controller.isWelcomeHeader ? false : true,
       child: const QuestionHeader()),
   SizeBox(
    height: ScreenUtil.screenHeight - marginQuestion,
      width: ScreenUtil.screenWidth,
   child: AlignTransition(
     alignment: controller.animation,
     child: SizedBox(
      height: ScreenUtil.screenHeight - marginQuestion,
      width: ScreenUtil.screenWidth,
      child: const Question(),
    ),
  ),),
 ],
);
```